# Altium telling me floating input pin

Tags: altium

When I try to compile my project Altium find a floating pin on block in a my schematic. I have tried to remove the wire and to make a new one to ensure the red cross appear well when placing the net and the wire but Altium keep telling me this is floating net (cf belows screensho[image]t).

What I am missing here ?

This schematic was imported in Altium directly from TI website, this is PMP9773 reference design.

Answer (score 2):

What else do you have on the EN_B net? If you don't commit to every symbol using Input/Output/Bidirectional settings, if you tie EN_B to some other port that has Passive or similar, that error will show up. It won't be a single-pin net, but a Passive pin connected to an Input pin will cause that error.

You can choose to go into Project Options and disable that specific ERC, but that carries its own set of risks if that is what you are depending on to catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It comes that the pin was connected to a net who has only one net with no connection anywhere.

Comment: This should not be its own answer, @KrunalDesai basically covered this in his answer. You should accept his and delete this one.

Comment: @derstrom8 I posted in the same time but you can remove mine if you want. I am not looking at being the one to get the more answer on stack exchange :) My score on the website doesn't matter, I am just a bit new at using Altium and happy to find some guru who have faced same problem than me before and who know how to solve this in few seconds whereas it would take me hours or days to find out what the problem is.